# dragging an element to the first position

Tags: jquery-ui

```
<div class='parent'>
<div class='children'>1234</div>
<div class='children'>5678</div>
<div class='children'>9101</div>
<div class='children'>I WANT TO BE FIRST</div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('.parent').sortable({
axis: "y",
containment: "parent"
});
```

There is a problem dragging an element to the first position if `containment` is set to `parent`. I need this settings but I also need to move some elements to the top. But it seams that there is no space enough to do it. Sometimes it is possible but mainly - it's not.

I tried with adding top/bottom padding/margin to the `parent` - without success.

Any workaround?

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bonaca/r4pbvo21/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try adding a 'hidden' element above, like so:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='children hidden'></div>
  <div class='children'>1234</div>
  <div class='children'>5678</div>
  <div class='children'>9101</div>
  <div class='children'>I WANT TO BE FIRST</div>
</div>
```

with this for css:

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

It won't release if dragged above the invisible element though.

here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj5eu4r8/5/)

Comment: Hm, interesting. It works, although the hidden el. will interfere with a lot of my existing js and php functions, but... let's say - solved

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a containing div and set the containment to it?  e.g.:

```
<div id="outer">
<div class='parent'>
<div class='children'>1234</div>
<div class='children'>5678</div>
<div class='children'>9101</div>
<div class='children'>I WANT TO BE FIRST</div>
</div>
</div>
```

along with:

```
$('.parent').sortable({
axis: "y",
containment: "#outer"
});
```

and

```
 #outer {
   padding-top: 1px;
 }
```

That seemed to work with the fiddle.